# Re-assembling two bytes in Java from C++, not getting expected result

Tags: java, c++, type-conversion, java-native-interface, byte

I am not getting the expected results when I tried to re-assemble the two bytes in Java (from C++ via JNI). Example below:

**C++:**

```cpp
uint8_t originalValue = 0x38;
uint8_t high = originalValue & 0x0f0;   //equals to 0x30
uint8_t low = originalValue << 4;       //equals to 0x80

sendByte(high);
delayNs(1);
sendByte(low);
```

**Java:**

```java
private int[] instructionRegister = new int[2];

private void processData(byte[] data) {
    if (data.length <= 0)
        return;
    if (data.length == 1) {
        int tmp = data[0];
        String hexTmp = ByteUtils.toHexString(false, (byte) tmp).toUpperCase();
        switch (tmp) {
            case CMD_INSTRUCTION: {
                log.info("\t>> INSTRUCTION: {}", hexTmp);
                processingInstruction = true;
                break;
            }
            case CMD_DATA: {
                log.info("\t>> DATA: {}", hexTmp);
                break;
            }
            default: {
                log.info("\t\t- {}", hexTmp);
                if (processingInstruction) {
                    if (instructionCount == 0) {
                        instructionRegister[0] = tmp;
                        instructionCount++;
                    } else {
                        instructionRegister[1] = tmp;
                        int combined = instructionRegister[0] | ((instructionRegister[1] >> 4);
                        log.info("\t>> Combined: ({}, {}) = {}",
                                ByteUtils.toHexString(false, (byte) instructionRegister[0]),
                                ByteUtils.toHexString(false, (byte) instructionRegister[1]),
                                ByteUtils.toHexString(false, (byte) combined));

                        instructionRegister = new int[2];
                        instructionCount = 0;
                        processingInstruction = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**Result:**

```
>> Combined: (30 , 80 ) = f8
```

I expected this to be **0x38** but got **0xF8**. When I manually did the calculation in speedcrunch, I get the expected results.

[image]

Comment: If you have `0x80` in a signed `byte` and then convert it to an `int` you get `0xffffff80`. So if you shift that and convert it to a byte again you get `f8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in my comment, the problem is converting a signed byte holding `0x80` to an `int` (using a widening conversion), because the byte is negative, and the sign then gets extended, so you get `ffffff80` in the `int`. If you then shift that to the right by 4 and convert back to a `byte`, you get: `0xf8`, and if you binary-or that with `0x30` it's still `0xf8`.

It looks like you're only doing such a conversion here:

```
int tmp = data[0];
```

You can change this line to:

```
int tmp = Byte.toUnsignedInt(data[0]);
```

To do a conversion as if the byte was unsigned.

---

To demonstrate the difference:

```
byte b = (byte) 0x80; // force overflow, making -128
int i1 = b;
int i2 = Byte.toUnsignedInt(b);

System.out.println(String.format("%x", b)); // 80
System.out.println(String.format("%x", i1)); // ffffff80
System.out.println(String.format("%x", i2)); // 80
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Makes sense now. I wasn't even aware that Byte.toUnsignedInt() existed.